# How to solve error Property does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**Problem**

I got this error from the code below for `.cropper`.

**error**

> Property 'cropper' does not exist on type 'never'.

**Question**

How to solve error on type never?

Here the code

```
export default function CropperDemo({ src, getCroppedFile,handleClose }:{src:any,getCroppedFile:any,handleClose:any}) {
  const cropperRef = useRef(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [scaleX, setScaleX] = useState(1);
  const [scaleY, setScaleY] = useState(1);

  const handleClick = () => {
    const imageElement = cropperRef?.current;
    const cropper = imageElement?.cropper;
    const img = cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL();
    getCroppedFile(img);
  };
  const rotate = () => {
    const imageElement = cropperRef?.current;
    const cropper = imageElement?.cropper;
    cropper.rotate(90);
  };
  const flip = (type) => {
    const imageElement = cropperRef?.current;
    const cropper = imageElement?.cropper;
    if (type === "h") {
      cropper.scaleX(scaleX === 1 ? -1 : 1);
      setScaleX(scaleX === 1 ? -1 : 1);
    } else {
      cropper.scaleY(scaleY === 1 ? -1 : 1);
      setScaleY(scaleY === 1 ? -1 : 1);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      {loading && (
        <Skeleton variant="rectangular" width={"100%"} height={400} />
      )}
      <Box display={"flex"} justifyContent={"flex-end"} mb={1}>
        <ButtonGroup disableElevation variant="contained">
          <Button onClick={rotate}>Rotate</Button>
          <Button onClick={() => flip("h")}>Flip H</Button>
          <Button onClick={() => flip("v")}>Flip V</Button>
        </ButtonGroup>
      </Box>

      <Cropper
        src={src}
        style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}
        // Cropper.js options
        initialAspectRatio={16 / 9}
        guides={false}
        ready={() => {
          setLoading(false);
        }}
        ref={cropperRef}
      />
      <Button
        sx={{
          float: "right",
          mt: 1
        }}
        onClick={handleClick}
        autoFocus
        color="success"
        variant="contained"
      >
        Crop
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: which line do you get this error?

Comment: this line const cropper = imageElement?.cropper;

Comment: what is the Cropper library you are using?

Comment: i use react-cropper

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because typeScript cannot determine the type of 'imageElement?.cropper' which leading to 'never' type.
You should write "const cropperRef = useRef(null)" instead of " const cropperRef = useRef(null)" because it seems like you are using 'react-easy-crop' library, and the 'cropperRef' is of type 'React.RefObject' so you have to specify the type of ref.
You can use, if (imageElement) before accessing properties like cropper on imageElement, you are checking if imageElement actually exists and is not null or undefined. This check helps TypeScript understand that the variable is not of type 'never', and it can safely proceed with accessing its properties.